# Meaning of capital pi symbol in sum over histories integral

Tags: notation, path-integral, mathematics, functional-determinants

This question is primarily mathematical in nature. I have been reading *Quantum Field Theory for the Gifted Amateur* and I am reading about Feynman’s path integral approach. The definition of the “sum over all paths integral” is given as including a capital pi symbol. For example,

[image]

I am familiar with the pi function as a modified gamma function and an extension of the factorial system, but I have never seen it listed with limits. If someone could explain the meaning of this notation or provide an alternate working definition of this integral, I would greatly appreciate.

(the image is not from the book, but it includes the pi symbol I am interested in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\prod_{j=1}^\infty$ means a product of what follows, with the factors having $j=1,2,3,\dots$. In this case there are an infinite number of factors so this is called an [infinite product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product). Infinite products can converge or diverge, just like infinite sums.

Comment: Thank you so much, not as hard as I thought